# Can someone please give me some practical application of liouville theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

All I understand is

liouville theorem states if f is entire on the domain specified,

and modulus of f is bounded for all z on the domain then f is identically constant.

This is all I know and all the other website I went to just shows proofs and proofs,

I really do not want to know proof but want to learn to use this theorem.

Can someone give me an example of application of liouville theorem?

(possibly such as Anayltic log, and how this Analytic log applies to this theorem)

Comment: Your formulation of Liouville't theorem leaves a lot to be desired. It says: An entire function (i.e. a function that is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$) which is bounded, must be constant. Your "on the domain specified" doesn't make any sense. It is important that the domain of definition is the whole complex plane.

Comment: Function can still be entire if I delete infinity from complex plane.

Comment: The point at infinity is **not** in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3):

It enables us to write a short proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: every (non-constant) polynomial over the complex numbers has a root. This is compelling motivation in my book.

Comment: this is not exactly the answer I want, I like to see how the function actually satisfies liouville theorem

Comment: @MathMA Do you want to see the proof that Liouville's theorem implies the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?

Comment: yes please thanks

Comment: I know we have an aversion to giving links here on Math SE. But you can find the proof in every undergrad text on complex analysis and many web pages. Here's one I just found:
http://www.math.uh.edu/~sanders/Math3364/fta.pdf If this link is broken at some time in the future, another search will certainly show up another.